# How can I push a JS variable into json

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sorry JS is not my language :-(

I should build such a json value:

```
var input = { 'to': { 'info@example.com' : 'Jhon Doe' }
```

I have read a ton of docs but i am stuck whith:

```
var userEmail = 'info@example.com'
var input = { 'to': { userEmail : 'Jhon Doe' }}
console.log(input);
// result-> userEmail: "Jhon Doe"
```

so, how can push a JS variable into json ?

Comment: That's not JSON but an object -> [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = { 'to': { [userEmail] : 'Jhon Doe' }}
```

`[userEmail]` will turn to the value of `userEmail`.

Alternatively:

```
var input = { 'to': {} };
input[userEmail] = 'Jhon Doe';
```

Comment: Just this!! Thak you very much, i spent few hours trying to it myself!!